# How can I replace a variable in a function with different values from a list in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am struggling with something simple. I have a list
`apple={10, 15, 25}`

and a function 
`f = 5*x + n`

I would like to get three functions that replace n with each of the elements of apple:
`5*x + 10`
`5*x + 15`
`5*x + 25`

I presume some simple dot-slash (./) operation ought to do this, but I cannot figure it out. Nor can I figure out how Map or Thread can do this. Do I need to resort to for loops?
Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks!
Sachin

I have tried the Map, Thread functions and various ./ attempts.

Comment: `apple={10,15,25};f=5*x+n;Map[f/.n->#&,apple]` returns `{10+5x,15+5x,25+5x}` You can look up `Map` and `/.` in the help system. The `#` and `&` are notation for "anonymous functions" that have no name but act like a function. What the example does is create a sort of function that takes an item from your list of functions and replaces the `n` with an item from your `apple` list and then does that for every item in your list. Study all this and see if you can make any sense of this.